# Can I output a one channel image acquired from camera into a winAppi window?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a pointer to an image acquired from acamera using  a third party SDK. The image is one band (Mono 8). I want to output it as a bittmap into a winAppi window. What i do is

```
        HBITMAP hBitmap = NULL;
        BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;
        bmih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
        bmih.biWidth = 1280;
        bmih.biHeight = 960;
        bmih.biPlanes = 1;
        bmih.biBitCount = 8;
        bmih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
        bmih.biSizeImage = 0;
        bmih.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmih.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
        bmih.biClrUsed = 0;
        bmih.biClrImportant = 0;

        BITMAPINFO dbmi;
        ZeroMemory(&dbmi, sizeof(dbmi));
        dbmi.bmiHeader = bmih;
        dbmi.bmiColors->rgbBlue = 0;
        dbmi.bmiColors->rgbGreen = 0;
        dbmi.bmiColors->rgbRed = 0;
        dbmi.bmiColors->rgbReserved = 0;

        void* bits = &aquiredImageCPU.m_sMemory.ptr()[0];

    hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(dc, &bmih, CBM_INIT, bits, &dbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);


    src = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
            SelectObject(src, hBitmap);
             BitBlt(dc, 10,10,512, 512, src, 0,   0,   SRCCOPY);
```

If i output the image as matrix and previou it using my library (a library where i use imsave similiar to matlabs imsave) i can see that the image is ok(grayscale image). But when i output it to winAppi window it tranforms it to RGB. I think it has to do with

```
          HDC dc = GetDC(hwnd);
          src = CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
```

Any suggestions?
Thank you

What i did in a similiar case is to take every 8 bits and to copy them 2 more times after the chunk of 8 bits. That works but it is costly and i need to have a real tile application.

```
        auto outputImageHight = 1280;
        auto outputImageWidth = 960;
        unsigned char *myArray = new unsigned char[3 * outputImageHight * outputImageWidth];

        for (int i = 0; i < outputImageHight; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < outputImageWidth; j++)
        {
        unsigned char ucTmp = (unsigned char)(image(i, j));

        myArray[3 * (i + outputImageHight * j) + 0] = ucTmp;
        myArray[3 * (i + outputImageHight * j) + 1] = ucTmp;
        myArray[3 * (i + outputImageHight * j) + 2] = ucTmp;
        }
```

Comment: The fastest and easiest way is via the [Windows Imaging Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wic/-wic-about-windows-imaging-codec) which you can use to transform the pixels into the appropriate format for display.

Comment: You're passing `DIB_PAL_COLORS` to `CreateDIBitmap`, which suggests that your bitmap doesn't contain pixels bur rather indexes to the color table.  Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: dsp_user you are right i had fixed that just forgot to update                                      hBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(dc, &bmih, CBM_INIT, bits, &dbmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

Comment: The chief problem here seems to be that you fail to clearly define what the image should look like. Windows strongly assumes the display is RGB (3 channels). You must somehow define how your single-channel image should be displayed. "Take every byte and copy it 2 times"  is somewhat of an answer, because that means R=G=B and thus you indeed have a greyscale image. Alternatively, define a 256 color palette (all greys) and you can use DIB_PAL_COLORS

Comment: The image should look like as the input image which is a one band 8 bit image(256 levels of gray). I have already done the "Take every byte and copy it 2 times" and it works fine. I didn't know that windows only assumes that the display is  RGB , i thought that there is a way to make windows assumes that i am using a one band image. "Alternatively, define a 256 color palette" can you give me some more information on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An 8-bit bitmap requires a color table.  Since you want grayscale, you have to set up the color table to have 256 levels of gray.  You've set the first one to black, which is correct, but you haven't set the rest.

BITMAPINFO is actually a variably sized structure.  The bmiColors field is just a placeholder for the first color in the color table.  You have to allocate extra space for the entire color table and fill it out.

```
std::size_t size = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + 256*sizeof(RGBQUAD);
std::vector<char> buffer(size);
BITMAPINFO *dbmi = reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFO *>(buffer.data());
ZeroMemory(dbmi, size); // probably unnecessary
dbmi->bmiHeader = bmih;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
  dbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = i;
  dbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = i;
  dbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = i;
  dbmi->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved = 0;
}
```

Comment: there's no such requirement that 8-bit bitmaps must use a color table. You can certainly encode the channels using only 2 or 3 bits (e.g `rrrgggbb`). In fact, if you want your 8-bit bitmaps to be portable across different platforms, you're not going to use a color table. That said, It's possible though that Windows supports only table based 8 bit bitmaps.

Comment: @dsp_user:  The color table I'm talking about creating is in memory to tell GDI how to interpret the pixel array.  You can either tell it you're using RGB, in which case you have to provide this color table to map the values to grayscale, or you tell it they're palette indexes, in which case you'll have to build a similar color table to set up the palette (yuck).

Comment: @dsp_user:  You're right that, in general, you can also encode the colors directly into the values.  But Windows supports that only for bit depths of 16 or 32.  8-bit pixel values are always indexes into either a color table or the palette.

Comment: Windows also supports 15-bit bitmaps as well as 24 bit bitmaps.    It's interesting that the docs is a bit incomplete regarding this though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd183376(v=vs.85). They don't mention 15 bit bitmaps at all.

Comment: @dsp_user:  15-bit bitmaps (555) are 16-bit bitmaps with one of the bits ignored; you have to use BI_BITFIELDS for those.  (BI_BITFIELDS is what works only with 16- and 32-bit depths.)  With BI_BITFIELDS, you set the masks in the one RGBQUAD that's part of the BITMAPINFOHEADER.  You can't use BI_BITFIELDS with 24-bit bitmaps; they're always 888, and they use BI_RGB.

Comment: I didn't use BI_BITFIELDS for 15/16 bit bitmaps but it wasn't plain `winapi` either to be honest. I used `VCL` to handle those bitmaps. Anyway, let's leave it there

Comment: FYI, when calling `delete [] dbmi`, you need to cast `dbmi` back to the correct type that `new[]` actually allocated, or else `delete[]` will not behave correctly: `delete [] reinterpret_cast<char>(dbmi);` in this case, I would use a `std::vector` instead: `std::vector<char> buffer(size); BITMAPINFO *dbmi = reinterpret_cast<BITMAPINFO *>(buffer.data());`

Comment: Edited to use `std::vector`, which I should have done from the start.  @Remy Lebeau shamed me into it by pointing out my `delete` error.  I'm not sure the cast-to-delete matters for POD, but RAII is always the better choice.